# retrieve the informations on click google map angular 2

Tags: google-maps, angular, google-maps-markers, marker

I'm trying to build an angular 2 application,i want to retrieve the address and all the informations of the clicked place on my google map.

Here is my code:

```
<sebm-google-map (mapClick)="getPosition($event)" [latitude]="lat" [longitude]="lng" [zoom]="zoom" [backgroundColor]="backgroundColor" style="margin-bottom:900px">
  <sebm-google-map-marker *ngFor=" let post of posts" [latitude]="post.lapti" [longitude]="post.longi" ></sebm-google-map-marker>
</sebm-google-map>
```

Any solution?

Answer (score 0):

Try this ,you can use it on **drag** :

```
<sebm-google-map [latitude]="lat" [longitude]="lng" [zoom]="zoom" class="content-map">
    <sebm-google-map-marker [latitude]="lat" [longitude]="lng" [markerDraggable]="true" (dragEnd)="getCordinates($event)">
    </sebm-google-map-marker>
</sebm-google-map>
```

For **click** use :

```
<sebm-google-map [latitude]="lat" [longitude]="lng" [zoom]="zoom" class="content-map">
    <sebm-google-map-marker [latitude]="lat" [longitude]="lng" (markerClick)="getCordinates($event)">
    </sebm-google-map-marker>
</sebm-google-map>
```

`(markerClick)="getCordinates($event)"` with `sebm-google-map-marker`

Comment: is it possible to retrieve other informations apart latitude and longitude?

Comment: you can console.log $event and check the params , @LaamiriOussema